# Counting problem of convex n-gon.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry

If we select k points randomly from the set of vertices of convex n-gon, what is the probability that each side of induced k-gon is diagonal of the n-gon?

Comment: Would "What is the probability that there is no pair of adjacent vertices among the chosen ones?" mean the same thing?

Comment: @Arthur I think in a regular hexagon removing two vertices on a line of symmetry will induce a diagonal even though there is 2 pairs of adjacent vertices.

Comment: @Coolwater I can't see which vertices you're talking about removing. Or even how many of them. Can you be a bit more explicit, like "vertex number $0, 3$ and $4$ as you go around"?

Comment: @Arthur removing 0,3 i thought

Comment: @Coolwater But those two aren't adjacent at all. So I don't see how that's a counterexample to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality let the vertices be $0,1,2,\dots,n-1$, and assume $0$ is one of the vertices. We need to select the other $k-1$ vertices. This can be done by selecting positive integers $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_{k-1}$ such that $a_i\geq 2$ and $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{k-1}\leq n-2$ and selecting the vertices of the form $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_i$.

The number of ways to do this is equal to the number of solutions in integers greater than $2$ to $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{k-1}\leq n-2$. This is clearly the number of solutions to $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k=n$ with each $a_i\geq 2$. This is equal to the number of solutions to $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k=n-2k$ with $a_i\geq 0$. By star and bars there are $\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$ solutions to this.

Hence the final answer is $\frac{\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}$

Comment: As a sanity check, let's consider an extreme case. Assume $n$ is even and $k = n/2$.  Then there is just one way to pick the vertices (all the even-numbered ones).  The numerator of your formula is ${n - n/2 - 1 \choose n/2 - 1} = {n/2 - 1 \choose n/2 -1} = 1$.